# CRUD with localization in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to create, read, update and destroy data with localization in laravel 5. please help me some suggestions thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Localization comes build in, check out the official docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization

Comment: I've checked it already but it tutorial only how to create translation in messages file and call it. For me, I want to insert data in multiple languages into database and read it out. Thanks for your answer 

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, for inserting and updating data, I don't think you can choose to localise your data: you have to insert ALL contents of ALL languages because you are saying you support these languages, right?

But for reading and displaying data, you can

1) Define columns with suffix. For example in post table you have columns called body_en, body_cn, body_jp etc.

2) When users choose to change languages, use a controller to respond to that action, **save a language suffix like '_en' into a cookie**, maybe called 'cookie_language'.

3) When users navigate in your site, for every request, use a middleware **check whether there is a language cookie, get its value, save it into session, and call `App::setLocale()` accordingly**.

4) When you retrieve data from post table, get the language value out of session, use it as suffix, like `Post::select(['body'.$suffix])->get()`. Localised data got!

5) Because you have set locale, now you can use `trans()` in all your views. View translated!

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's mean, I have static languages field my database but I want to insert from dynamic input depend on number of languages to database. is it possible? Thanks for your answer above it's helpful.